# Chrome don't send back cookie

Tags: rest, google-chrome, http, cookies, sapui5

I have a web app. To work it usestwo server:

- Application server (based on Delphi datasnap) SERV_A
- WebServer apache SERV_W

These are the user steps:

**STEP1 Login**

The user call index page from SERV_W, write user and password and call a procedure by HTTP POST to SERV_A. SERV_A respond by a session_id passed by a Cookie (response header has `Set-Cookie: sessionid=123456`)

**STEP2 Get url list**

The user call another SERV_A procedure by HTTP GET to retrieve a *list* of url
For example an url is:  http://host_serv_a:port/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/getPDF/003

**STEP3 Click on a link**

The user sees a list of link and click on one of those.
Automatically the browser do an HTTP GET to retrieve the resource to SERV_A.

Ok, this is my problem:
On STEP3 SERV_A want the sessionId, passed in a cookie but the browser never send the cookie. Why?  My browser (Chrome) don't have limitation to manage cookie.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution here https://divshot.com/blog/static-apps/cookies-and-cors/ (Web Standards Are Awesome)

To manage cookies correctly server and client have to agree:

- **Client**: set `withCredentials` option to `true` in the ajax call
- **Server**: set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header in the response